# Find $P(A\ xor\ B\ |\ A\ \cup\ B)$

Tags: self-study, conditional-probability

I'm self-studying a textbook ([Larsen and Marx](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321693949)) (not for course credit) and wanted to post my solution to a problem related to conditional probability.

Given:

$$
\begin{align}
&P((A \cup B)^C) = 0.6 \\
&P(A \cap B) = 0.1 \\
&E = A\ xor\ B\ \text{(A or B but not both)}
\end{align}
$$

Find $P(E\ |\ A \cup B)$

Below is my solution. Is this correct or else where did I go wrong?

$$
\begin{align}
P(E\ |\ A \cup B) &= \frac{P(E\ \cap\ (A \cup B))}{P(A \cup B)} \tag 1 \\ 
\\
P(E\ \cap (A \cup B)) &= P((E \cap A)\ \cup\ (E \cap B)) \tag 2 \\
\\
&= P((A \cup B) \cup (A \cup B)) \\
\\
&= P(A \cup B) \\
\\
\therefore \\
\\
P(E\ |\ A \cup B) &= \frac{P(A \cup B)}{P(A \cup B)} = 1 \tag 3 \\
\\
\end{align}
$$

Noting that $E \cap B$ = [(A xor B) or B] = $A \cup B$ and similarly $E \cap A$ = [(A xor B) or A] = $A \cup B$.

Comment: You've made a mistake. To help you find your mistake, try drawing a Venn diagram showing $A$, $B$ and $E$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First fine $P(E))$
\begin{align*}
P(E) & =P((A\cup B)\setminus(A\cap B))\\
 & =P(A\cup B)-P(A\cap B)\\
 & =.4-.1=.3
\end{align*}
and then note that $E\cap(A\cup B)$ is simply $E$:
\begin{align*}
P(E|A\cup B) & =\frac{P\left(E\cap\left(A\cup B\right)\right)}{P(A\cup B)}\\
 & =\frac{P(E)}{P(A\cup B)}=.3/.4=\frac{3}{4}
\end{align*}