# Finding the $P(E \mid A \cup B)$

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Let $A$ and $B$ be two events such that $P((A \space $U$ \space B)^c) = 0.6$ and $P(A \cap B) = 0.1$. Let $E$ be the event that either $A$ or $B$ but not both will occur. Find $P(E \mid A \space $U$ \space B)$.

What I have tried: $P((A \space $U$\space B)^c) = 0.6 = 1-P(A \space $U$\space B) \space$. Therefore, $\space P(A \space $U$ \space B) = 0.4$.

For either event $A$ or $B$ to occur and not both, we have

$$E = P(A\cap B^c)\cup P(A^c\cap B)$$

So we now have:

$$\begin{align} P(E \mid A\cup B) &= \frac{P((A\cap B^c)\cup (A^c\cap B))\cap P(A\cup B)}{P(A \cup B)} \\ &= \frac{P((A\cap B^c)\cup (A^c\cap B))\cap 0.4}{0.4} \end{align}$$

I'm not sure how to get $P(A)$ from $P(A^c\cap B)$ when $P(A^c\cap B) = P(A) - P(A\cap B)$.

Comment: Draw either the Venn diagram or the probability tree: the answer will drop right out from an inspection of it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find $P(A\ xor\ B\ |\ A\ \cup\ B)$](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/327963/find-pa-xor-b-a-cup-b)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
P((A \cap B)^C\mid A \cup B) =
\tfrac{P(A \cap B)^C \cap (A \cup B)}{P(A \cup B)} = 
\tfrac{P(A \cup B)-P(A \cap B)}{P(A \cup B)} = \tfrac{0.3}{0.4}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{align}
E &= (A \cap \bar{B}) \cup (\bar{A} \cap B) \\
&= ([A \cap \bar{B}] \cup \bar{A}) \cap ([A \cap \bar{B}] \cup B) \\
&= ([A \cup \bar{A}] \cap [\bar{A} \cup \bar{B}]) \cap ([A \cup B] \cap [B \cup \bar{B}]) \\
&= (\bar{A} \cup \bar{B}) \cap (A \cup B) \\
&= (\overline{A \cap B}) \cap (A \cup B)
\end{align}
$$
So
$$
\begin{align}
P(E|A \cup B) &= \frac{P((\overline{A \cap B}) \cap (A \cup B) \cap (A \cup B))}{P(A \cup B)} \\
&= \frac{P((\overline{A \cap B}) \cap (A \cup B))}{P(A \cup B)}
\end{align}
$$
Using De Morgan's law
$$
\begin{align}
P((\overline{A \cap B}) \cap (A \cup B)) &= 1 - P((\overline{\overline{A \cap B})\cap (A \cup B)}) \\
&= 1 - P((A \cap B) \cup (\overline{A \cup B}))
\end{align}
$$
Since the events $A \cap B$ and $\overline{A \cup B}$ are disjoint, then
$$
\begin{align}
P((\overline{A \cap B}) \cap (A \cup B)) &= 1 - P(A \cap B) - P(\overline{A \cup B}) \\
&= 1 - 0.1 - 0.6 \\
&= 0.3
\end{align}
$$
And so
$$
\begin{align}
P(E|A \cup B) &= \frac{P((\overline{A \cap B}) \cap (A \cup B) \cap (A \cup B))}{P(A \cup B)} \\
&= \frac{0.3}{0.4} \\
&= 0.75
\end{align}
$$